# Inserting data into pyqt Qtablewidget

Tags: python, pyqt

I am inserting mysql data into a pyqt Qtablewidget but when I pass the data to one variabel the data is printed to only one cell into the table. Any suggestions?

My code:

```
import sys
import MySQLdb as mdb
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
db = mdb.connect('server','user','password','db')

model = db.cursor()
model.execute("""SELECT ip
                    FROM table""")
rows_pong = (model.fetchall())
data = "\n".join(item[0] for item in rows_pong)
print data

lista = [data]
listb = ['ba', 'bb', 'bc']
mystruct = {'A':lista, 'B':listb}

class MyTable(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, thestruct, *args): 
        QTableWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        self.data = thestruct
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['IP Address', 'Username'])
        self.setmydata()

    def setmydata(self):
        for n, key in enumerate(self.data):
            for m, item in enumerate(self.data[key]):
                newitem = QTableWidgetItem(item)
                self.setItem(m, n, newitem)

def main(args):
    app = QApplication(args)
    table = MyTable(mystruct, 100, 3)
    table.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__=="__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Sample Data (items in the variable):

```
10.10.0.171:139

10.10.0.171:139

127.0.0.1:3306

127.0.0.1:20128

127.0.0.1:20129

127.0.0.1:20130

127.0.0.1:20130

127.0.0.1:20131

127.0.0.1:20131

127.0.0.1:61335

127.0.0.1:61561

127.0.0.1:61562

127.0.0.1:61942

127.0.0.1:61943

127.0.0.1:62291

127.0.0.1:62292

127.0.0.1:63093

127.0.0.1:63094
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working as expected for me. Not sure if it was intended but `lista` consists of one item since you are joining the results of the query into a single string. Try replacing `data = "\n".join(item[0] for item in rows_pong)` with `data = [item[0] for item in rows_pong]` and change `lista = [data]` to `lista = data` if you want each IP to show up in a new row.

Comment: It doesn't work :/, the data = "\n".join(item[0] for item in rows_pong) is the component generating the test data.

Comment: `data = "\n".join(item[0] for item in rows_pong)` generates a single string, instead of a list of strings. Is that intended (i.e. do you want all the IPs to appear in a single QTableWidget cell?). 

Did not realize mysqldb returned nested tuples in this case. Changed my answer to `data = [item[0] for item in rows_pong]` -- hope that works.